# Transform data with time stamp from row to column in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql

I have table where the columns are structured as rows. Currently i have a key column where all the columns are entered and a value columns where the results of entered

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WWZ8.png)
i need to extract the vlaues from key columns and thier corresponsing values as per column.

if key column has 22820430 then the value has to be extracted into a new column and name it as plantier. similarly for status in the key column and its corresponsing value.

Below is the code i tried. All the events are uniques ones and are having a time stamp of when those events have happened which is under the created_at column. I am not looking for the time stamp of those events i just need the value. however the only time stamp i need for each tickets are the created date and when status is closed the closed date
There will be multiple values for status and 22820430(plantier) i need the last recorded value of those only.

Note: I cannot use crosstab function

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyPkG.png)

```
select te.ticket_id,t.type,t.created_at,
max(case when te.key = 22820430 then te.value end) as plan_tier,
max(case when te.key = 'status' then te.value end) as status,
max(case when te.key = 360050595934 then te.value end) as category
from ticket_events te
join tickets t on te.created_at = t.created_at
where t.created_at > '2023-06-01' /*and ticket_id = '2638452'*/
group by te.ticket_id,t.type,t.created_at
order by t.created_at desc
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgehS.png)

Comment: Please refer to [ask], specifically the guiidance regarding not posting images of textual content and the [rationale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Also, please correct the formatting: the closing code fence, `\`\`\``, must be on a line by itself.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL?

Comment: Please only ask a question once. If you need to rephrase a question or add additional details, then edit the original question. You've essentially asked this question again in a later post. Even though this post predates the other, I'm flagging this one as the duplicate because the other has received more activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PARTITION and CASE statement together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76733778/how-to-use-partition-and-case-statement-together)