# How to use PARTITION and CASE statement together

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add a `CASE` statement after a partition and I am getting null data in the new column that I created using case statement.

Code I am trying:

```
select te.ticket_id,te.created_at,
max(case when te.key = 22820430 then te.value end) as plan_tier
from (select *,row_number()over(partition by te.ticket_id order by te.created_at)rn
from ticket_events te ) te
where rn=1 and te.created_at > '2023-06-01'
group by te.ticket_id,te.created_at
order by te.created_at desc
```

I have a ticket table with time stamp for different events within the ticket. I need to add in new columns that is within the ticket events table as rows.

`te.key` is the columns in ticket events table and `te.value` has the corresponding value.

These are the columns that I need to pull from the events table (under key) and create a new table:

te.key = 22820430 as plan_tier
te.key = 'status' as status
te.key = 'type' as ticket_type

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZHCe.png)

I am trying to have one row for each ticket by the ticket created date which I have already done using the partition. Need to map the rest of the columns into each ticket.

[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebslk.png)

Comment: Please present a query readable for human eyes, sample data and result as text (never as image), and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns the required results:

```
WITH ticket_events(id, created_date, KEY, value) AS (
  VALUES (1, '2023-06-12'::date, '22820430', 'a'),
         (1, '2023-06-10'::date, 'status', 'new'),
         (1, '2023-06-16'::date, 'status', 'closed'),
         (1, '2023-06-19'::date, 'type', 'question'),
         (2, '2023-06-12'::date, '22820430', 'b'),
         (2, '2023-06-10'::date, 'status', 'closed'),
         (2, '2023-06-16'::date, 'status', 'pending'),
         (2, '2023-06-19'::date, 'type', 'problem'))
SELECT te.id AS "Ticket ID",
       (array_agg(te.value ORDER BY te.created_date DESC) filter (WHERE te.key = 'type'))[1] AS "Ticket Type",
       (array_agg(te.value ORDER BY te.created_date DESC) filter (WHERE te.key = '22820430'))[1] AS "Ticket Plan Tier",
        min(te.created_date) AS "Ticket Created Date",
       (array_agg(te.value ORDER BY te.created_date DESC) filter (WHERE te.key = 'status'))[1] AS "Ticket Status"
  FROM ticket_events te
GROUP BY "Ticket ID"
ORDER BY "Ticket ID";
```

The `FILTER` clause is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions such as `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`. To get around this limitation,`ARRAY_AGG` is used to collect the filtered values within each group. The values are sorted in descending date order so that the first element of each array is the most recently assigned for the given `key`.

Comment: I am getting the following error when i tried the code.ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 2: (array_agg(te.value ORDER BY te.created_at DESC) filter (WHE...

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? I'm using 15.3 on a MacBook and just verified that the posted code works in psql and pgAdmin v7.4.

Comment: Sorry, it is working in my pgAdmin tool but it is not working in amazon redshift Postgres.